# Fast way to compare rows of a matrix two by two?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a code, repeats several time during running. This code compares the rows of `C` two by two. It takes long time to run, specially for large `C`. I am looking for a fast way to run that. I have used `a(ismember(a,b)))` instead of `intersect(a,b)`.

```
     I = size (C,1);
     for i = 1 : I-1,
        for j = i+1 : I,
            a=C(i,:);
            b=C(j,:);
            if sum(a(ismember(a,b)))-sum(b)==0,
                n = n+1;
                K(n) = j;
                K1(n) = i;
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: What's the typical datasize for `C`?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. The number of rows of `C` could be up to 1500, tipically. It has fewer columns (up to 5).

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @ knedlsepp: I want to find rows that are redundant. Redundant rows are those have the a subset of elements of other rows and zeros. for example if `C=[17 18 5;3 5 7;17 18 0;4 17 2;5 0 0]`, then `C(3,:)` and `C(5,:)` are redundant. Therfore `n=2`, `K=[3 5 5]`, and `K1n=[1 1 2]`

Comment: @Meher81: Your original code does not do exactly what you are describing with your comment. This is only valid if the entries of `C` are not negative.

Comment: @ knedlsepp: Please run the example in my previous comment. It work exactly as I described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be one [`vectorized`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) approach -

```
%// Get the size of C and pairwise indices
N = size(C,1);
[Y,X] = find(bsxfun(@gt,[1:N]',[1:N])); %//'

%// Form the two pairs
p1 = C(X,:);
p2 = C(Y,:);

%// Get the matches for each element in a row against all other elements in
%// the matching row pair combinations. This would be equivalent to
%// ISMEMBER implementation in the original code
matches = squeeze(any(bsxfun(@eq,permute(p1,[3 2 1]),permute(p2,[2 3 1])),1));
matches = reshape(matches,[],numel(Y)); %//for special case when C has 2 rows

%// Get linear indices that satisfy the equality criteria from original code
idx = find(sum(matches.'.*p1,2) == sum(p2,2)); %//'

%// Store the row and column information from the linear indices
K_vectorized = Y(idx);
K1_vectorized = X(idx);
```

Comment: Your code dose not work for some C. I can not find the reason. For example, please test it for `C=[3,4,0,0;4,8,0,0;]`

Comment: @ Divakar: `C` contains zero and positive integer numbers.

Comment: @Meher81 Had to add one line to handle that special case. Check it out now.